# Deploying portlet with a liferay on cloudbees

Tags: liferay, liferay-6, portlet, cloudbees, liferay-theme

I succed to deploy a liferay 6.1.1 on cloudbees thanks to this tutorial :
http://blog.cloudbees.com/2011/09/15-minutes-to-liferay-on-cloudbees-paas.html

Now, I'm asking how to deploy themes and custom portlets in this environment is there a way, or should I switch to another Paas solution?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

You can either repackage liferay with the portlets into the "stack" and deploy that - or you can have liferay load the portlets from something other than the file system (filesystem support is needed for this to load dynamically, which is a work in progress).